# Blender 2.78 doesn't render png textures

Tags: texturing

Since I installed 2.78 image textures from png are no longer rendered. Jpg is working but can't be made transparant. It looks like there's a bug here.

Comment: PNGs works fine in 2.78 here. Is it all PNGs? Have you verified the path is correct, and these PNGs can be opened in other software? What do you mean by 'not rendered'? Black? Pink (error color)?

Comment: Same problem here. Alpha is on but still its pink. JPG works well. Also in the preview window is rendered correctly, but in the main renderview is pink.

Comment: Some screen shots of your material/texture settings would be hugely helpful

Answer (score -3):

You have to select Image texture node and in settings on the right (those which are apearing when press N ) and enable Use Alpha. For some reason it's off by default in 2.78.

Comment: This assumes cycles, which was not specified by the answer. Either clarify with the OP about which engine, or update the answer for both cycles and internal.

Comment: There is another option, which you didn't mention. I just leave it like it is. Cheers.

Comment: ....and get a downvote ;)

Comment: @Mzidare Thanks for helping others, but please [take downvotes for what they are, not what they are not](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/496/599). You are free to write your answer how you see fit, but don't be too surprised if such a short answer gets some downvotes.

Comment: My answer turned out to be helpful for someone, cause was upvoted. The problem is not very popular, cause most of Blender users easily manage to solve it themselves. It's very easy, so the answer is short ans simple. I don't believe, that this forum is red by idiots and walking people step by step through such straight forward situation is not necessary. If you are concerned @gandalf3 about users well being, then edit my answer, and if it will be legit, I'll accept this change. This are my arguments, what are yours?

Comment: @Mzidare I would, but to be honest, without more info I don't know what could be causing the problem the OP is experiencing. If I was sure I understood the question, then I would've likely written an answer already ;)

Comment: @gandalf3 Well, I wrote the answer cause I know what's wrong in this case. I had the same situation and was able to correctly guestimate it. It considers only Cycles, so It's pointless to mention BI in this particular case and that's why I didn't apply GiantCowFilms request and answered him in the way I did.

Comment: @Mzidare Okay, and that's quite fine. My response was to the seemingly heated nature of your reply to GiantCowFilms. I wish to make it clear that downvoting in and of itself shouldn't be taken as a personal attack.